# Can plugin variables cause conflict?

Tags: plugins

I write a wordpress plugin. My plugin code in inside a class.

```
if (!class_exists("Pluginname")) {
  class Pluginname {
    ...
  }
}

if (class_exists("Pluginname")) {
  $obj = new Pluginname;
}
```

Question: What if `$obj` is already used in Wordpress code or in another plugin? Can this be a potential source of conflict? If so, what to do?

Comment: Prefix it, if your plugin is called something like My Events Calendar, put a mec_ in front of your ALL your globally scoped (outside of a class) functions, class names and variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can. Say you have plugin one, with only this:

```
// Plugin one
$variable = "henk";
```

And then you have plugin two, with only this:

```
// Plugin two
echo $variable;
```

And now you activate these plugins, you will probably see the variable of plugin one echo'd by plugin two (at least it did here, but I don't know what determines the sequence).

It's probably best to use a sort of prefix like $my_plugin_variable if you're not using it inside a function or class.